# Convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+.....\frac{1}{(2n)^2}$

1.converges to $0$.

2.converges to $1/2$.

3.converges to $1/4$.

4.Does not converge.

I think 2 is correct answer because $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(n+k)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(n^2)(1+k/n)^2}$$\rightarrow \int_1^2 \frac{1}{x^2}dx=1/2$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Isn't $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2$ a convergent series?

Comment: It's not correct, the Riemann sum you seem to have in mind would be $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n\,(1+k/n)^2}.$$ Moreover, your $a_n$ is the sum of $n+1$ terms $\le 1/n^2$, so it must clearly converge to $0$.

Comment: You have $n+1$ positive terms, the largest of them being $\frac{1}{n^2}$. Their sum is positive and bounded by $\frac{n+1}{2n^2}$, hence the first option is obviously the correct one. There is no need for Riemann sums.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s_m:=\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k^2}$. Then $s_m \to \pi^2/6$ for $m \to \infty$. Hence

$a_n=s_{2n}-s_{n-1} \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that it isn't really important for the problem to know what exactly $s_m$ converges to, just that it converges by using a standard convergence test.

Comment: Thanks everyone for correcting me.